# A Loooooong Sequence of Calculations

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, lateral-thinking

> $53466+25123+16334+86556+5856\cdot 32454+8565+2235+7067-2345\cdot  1086+|23457|+4754\cdot 89510+9523-3458-9234+84233-|947\cdot 137\cdot 98\cdot 142-407119|\cdot (-1024)\cdot 5^{10}+645\cdot 9814\cdot 181+7554\cdot 235+|346\cdot 23+646-979+2357-846-123\cdot 54-1210|\cdot 12-454\cdot 7542+145\cdot 686\cdot 12+239\cdot 145+2454-234560+633+9565-|124\cdot 45\cdot 23\cdot 46-23423+9878-45642-2345\cdot 996+454\cdot 2456\cdot 489+123\cdot 85+235\cdot 79|+14677-12414+9676-23467-123\cdot |85\cdot 102|+117455\cdot 4078+346+2358+3489+34655\cdot 3432+194\cdot 253\cdot 236+231$

**The answer to this puzzle is a single word (8).**

Subtle Hints:

> $5\cdot 19=95$

> There's something fishy about these numbers. Definitely need to take closer look at things...

Moderate Hints:

> Note that there's no [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag! This is not a math puzzle.

> You can ignore the parentheses, they don't mean anything.

Decisive Hints:

> I've added the [visual](/questions/tagged/visual) tag. At first, it might not seem obvious where the "visual" part is, but try to think about the first subtle hint again.

> It's all hidden in plain sight...

Comment: Big apologies to all the solvers: I just realized that I had made a major error in the equation, and have corrected it just now.

Comment: Apparently I'm completely illiterate and said "to reprimand" solvers in the bounty description *facepalm* I meant "to compensate".

Comment: You were likely thinking about "to recompense", though "to compensate" works too.

Comment: Even still, got no idea what the _totally random numbers_ mean.

Comment: @Stevo These numbers definitely aren't "totally random" ;)

Comment: dot (.) means multiple and | is division right? @JerryDean

Comment: @skyBlue I interpreted the first hint  "x is the mutliplication sign, not dot (.) ". I may be wrong.  | is for absolute value, but my understanding is that we should not consider the puzzle as a mathematics one....

Comment: @skyBlue dot means multiple, but |x| means the absolute value of x.

Comment: @franckvivien That's not my intention. Try to consider the new hints I just added.

Comment: Well, didn't figure anything out but it helped inspire me to write a new puzzle xD

Comment: I know that this is slightly out of bounds, but it's very interesting to me that your puzzle edits consisted of changing a written-out multiplication of two numbers to their product. This has helped me not at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> **EQUATION**

The numbers in the equation ...

> ... should be ignored. The moderate hint tells us that the parentheses can be ignored, too. That leaves us with a series of dots, plus and minus signs and vertical bars:
>
> ++++·+++−·+||+·+−−+−|···−|·−·+··+·+|·+−+−−·−|·−
> ·+··+·+−++−|···−+−−·+··+·+·|+−+−−·|·|+·++++·+··+

Note that ...

> ... there are 95 symbols in this series. The subtle hint tells us that 5·19 = 95. Let's split the series into five chunks of 19 symbols:
>
>      ++++·+++−·+||+·+−−+
>      −|···−|·−·+··+·+|·+
>      −+−−·−|·−·+··+·+−++
>      −|···−+−−·+··+·+·|+
>      −+−−·|·|+·++++·+··+
>
>  Let's also replace the dots with spaces and use a fixed-width font so that all lines have the same visual length:
>
> ```
>      + + + +   + + + −   + | | +   + − − +
>      − |       − |   −   +     +   + |   +
>      − + − −   − |   −   +     +   + − + +
>      − |       − + − −   +     +   +   | +
>      − + − −   |   | +   + + + +   +     +
> ```

Hmm. And now?

> We have three symbols: a vertical stroke, a horizontal stroke and a combination of those. We can separate the sketch into one of only horizontal and one of only vertical strokes:
>
> ```
>      − − − −   − − − −   −     −   − − − −
>      −         −     −   −     −   −     −
>      − − − −   −     −   −     −   − − − −
>      −         − − − −   −     −   −     −
>      − − − −         −   − − − −   −     −
>
>      | | | |   | | |     | | | |   |     |
>        |         |       |     |   | |   |
>        |         |       |     |   |   | |
>        |         |       |     |   |   | |
>        |       |   | |   | | | |   |     |
> ```

Comment: That is correct! Also, rot13(Vs lbh npghnyyl cresbez gur pnyphyngvbaf, lbh jbhyq neevir ng n 20-qvtvg ahzore. Vs lbh fcyvg vg vagb 10 2-qvtvg ahzoref, gurl jbhyq nyy or jvguva 1 naq 26. Genafyngvat gur erfhyg ol N1M26 tvirf "erq ureevat".)